# "error":"Bad Request","message":"Required int parameter 'customerId' is not present",

Tags: ios, json, swift4, multipartform-data, nsurlsession

i am trying to upload an image to server, but it's showing response like this

> response is : {
>       error = "Bad Request";
>       message = "Required int parameter 'customerId' is not present";
>       path = "/GroceryShoppingCartApplication/customer/uploadProfileImage";
>       status = 400;
>       timestamp = "2018-09-19T04:52:03.849+0000"; }

i was searched so many links, but my problem is not solved.Please suggest me correct code.

Here is my code:

```
func myImageUploadRequest()
    {

        let myUrl = NSURL(string: "myUrl.....");


        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url:myUrl! as URL);
        request.httpMethod = "POST";


        let headers = [
            "content-type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW",
            "Authorization": "bearer ff824d51-3c18-4efb-b6cf-70c33c78ac76",
            "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
            "Postman-Token": "8d576d32-1c29-f994-4337-b08e1aad60e9"
        ]

        let param = [
            "customerId":"3"
        ]

        let boundary = generateBoundaryString()

        let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(myImageView.image!, 1)
        if(imageData==nil)  { return; }
        request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
        request.httpBody = createBodyWithParameters(parameters: param, filePathKey: "imageFile", imageDataKey: imageData! as NSData, boundary: boundary) as Data
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
            data, response, error in

            if error != nil {
                print("error=\(error)")
                return
            }
            print("******* response = \(response)")
            let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
            print("****** response data = \(responseString!)")

            do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [])
                print("response is :",json)
            }catch
            {
                print(error)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }

    func createBodyWithParameters(parameters: [String: String]?, filePathKey: String?, imageDataKey: NSData, boundary: String) -> NSData {
        let body = NSMutableData();

        if parameters != nil {
            for (key, value) in parameters! {

                print("getting key is:",key)
                print("getting value is:",value)

                body.appendString(string: "--\(boundary)\r\n")
                body.appendString(string: "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"; value=\"\(value)\"\r\n")
            }
        }

        let filename = "user-profile.png"

        let mimetype = "image/png"

        body.appendString(string: "--\(boundary)\r\n")
        body.appendString(string: "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(filePathKey!)\"; filename=\"\(filename)\"\r\n")
        body.appendString(string: "Content-Type: \(mimetype)\r\n\r\n")
        body.append(imageDataKey as Data)
        body.appendString(string: "\r\n")

        body.appendString(string: "--\(boundary)--\r\n")

        return body
    }

    func generateBoundaryString() -> String {
        return "Boundary-\(NSUUID().uuidString)"
    }
}

extension NSMutableData {

    func appendString(string: String) {
        let data = string.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: true)
        append(data!)
    }
}
```

Comment: did you try to change your param to `"customerId": 3`(3 is Int type, not String type)

Comment: i tried it, but it showing same response

Comment: Try sending customerId in the header part !

Comment: i tried it just now, i am not getting any response, when i checked my code in postman it's working.in post man customer id and image both sending in 
form-data body only.

Comment: check your createBodyWithParameters method how it is formatting the data .

Comment: try this `body.append("--\(boundary)\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)` instead of `body.appendString(string: "--\(boundary)\r\n")` for all param

Comment: no use, it's getting same response.